# Why View Fragment is null in AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

This is my Fragment class:

public class StanzeFragment extends Fragment {

```
public StanzeFragment(){}

Button vis_stanze;
public TextView testo;

View rootView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_log_stanze, container, false);
    testo = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.testo);

    vis_stanze = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.bottone_stanze);
    vis_stanze.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            getStanze backgroundTask = new getStanze();
            backgroundTask.execute();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
    }

public void setTesto(String value){
    testo.setText(value);
     }
    }
```

But now i need to call method "setTesto" in other class (AsyncTask class), in onPostExecute method:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      StanzeFragment test = new StanzeFragment();
        test.setTesto(result);
    }
```

He give me this error:

" java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.androidnuovosa.bocci.navdriwerdb.Utente.StanzeFragment.setTesto(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference" ..
..I think because he don't see View of Fragment, how can I resolve this problem?
Thnks for answer. (I have this problem for other class too)

EDIT:

AsyncTask isn't in StanzeFragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Fragments` are supposed to be instantiated by the system (as they are defined in the layout XML) or from the code by using the [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) methods.

If you just instantiate a `StanzeFragment` like that, it does not actually appear on the view stack and its `testo` `TextView` is `null`. **This** seems to be your problem.

In your case apparently the `Fragment` is already visible when the `AsyncTask` runs, you should just get a reference to that `Fragment` instance instead of creating a new one.

The `FragmentManager` has methods to find a `Fragment` either by the `id` (as defined in the XML) or by the `tag` (given when showing it programmatically):

[findFragmentById()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById(int))

[findFragmentByTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String))

**EDIT:**

In your layout XML for an `Activity` you probably have a `Fragment`:

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.example.MyFragment"
        android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
    ... />
```

Now depending on the exact configuration of your app (the `Activity` type actually) you will call either:

[getFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getFragmentManager())

...or...

[getSupportFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager())

...so, for example:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

to access the `FragmentManager`. And then you find your `MyFragment` with its id `my_fragment`:

```
MyFragment myFrag = (MyFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment);
```

This should all be done in the `Activity` which contains the said `Fragment`.

Another (alternative) way to keep references to Fragments would be to implement the `onAttachFragment()` method in your `Activity`. (In the `Activity` which will contain the said `Fragment`):

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);

    if (fragment instanceof StanzeFragment) {
        stanzeFragment = (StanzeFragment) fragment;
    }
}
```

The `onAttachFragment()` method is ran when your `Fragment` is constructed and shown by the system. The exact wording in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onAttachFragment(android.app.Fragment)) is

> Called when a Fragment is being attached to this activity, immediately
>   after the call to its Fragment.onAttach() method and before
>   Fragment.onCreate().

So at that point the `Fragment` isn't completely ready yet, but this anyway gets a reference to the correct `Fragment` instance which actually will appear on the device screen. So when you later in your code use `stanzeFragment` you can access its TextViews and whatnot.

Comment: Hi, tnks for the answer. Can you show me an exemple? I create an object of my fragment : `StanzeFragment test = new StanzeFragment();` and now? what i need?

Comment: But i have a problem, my fragment isn't in this activity, is in another activity.. infact in this activity i haven't <fragment ...../> .. how can i call fragment which belongs in other activity? If i create <fragment.. /> with StanzeFragment layout He begins to merge the two fragment

Comment: I can't comment on your overall app. architecture, but as I have understood, the basic idea is that the `Activity` containing the `Fragment` should have access to the data that is to be provided to the `Fragment` and will receive the data that's possibly entered by the user with the UI components in that `Fragment`. You could either bring the necessary data to the `Activity` that has a reference to the `Fragment` or share the `Fragment` reference to the other `Activity`. I think the latter option sounds worse as then a "foreign" `Activity` would have access to the `Fragment`.

Comment: " bring the necessary data to the Activity that has a reference to the Fragment" i need this, but how? 
I tried everything

Comment: Maybe [Google's documentation on Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) would give some ideas of a proper app. architecture as it covers topics all the way from "design philosophy" to Fragment - Activity communication. (Which explains the onAttach() and onFragmentAttach() methods by the way.)

Comment: They are many ways two Activities can communicate. That's a separate topic on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing the AsyncTask inside your StanzeFragment, you just do this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    setTesto(result);
}
```

Comment: This is the problem, asyncTask isn't inside StanzeFragment

Comment: i can see that on click of `vis_stanze`, you execute the AsyncTask. My suggestion should fix your problem.

Comment: Mmh yes i fix this problem with your answer but in other class i have same problem.. you don't know why all View values are null?

Comment: you can accept this as an answer to close the question. then check Markus' reply. :)

Comment: sorry but i'm noob in stack, how can i close my question?